# Coefficients table does not display results for both independent variables after running GEE

Tags: r, regression, coefficients

I have a simple question here. I use the `gee` package to run a gee regression on the data below. I used the same dataset in spss and took this table as result.

[image]

## dataset

```
round<-c( 0.125150,  0.045800, -0.955299, -0.232007,  0.120880, -0.041525,  0.290473, -0.648752,  0.113264, -0.403685)
    square<-c(-0.634753,  0.000492, -0.178591, -0.202462, -0.592054, -0.583173, -0.632375, -0.176673, -0.680557, -0.062127)
    ideo<-c(0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1)
    ex<-data.frame(round,square,ideo)
```

When I run the same analysis in r

```
library(gee)  
    exmen<-summary(gee(round ~ square,
                        data = ex, id = ideo,
                        corstr = "independence"))
    exmen
```

I get:

```
Coefficients:
            Estimate Naive S.E. Naive z Robust S.E. Robust z
(Intercept)   -0.510      0.181   -2.82       0.229    -2.23
square        -0.939      0.399   -2.36       0.404    -2.32
```

The same happens with `geepack` package

```
library(geepack)
    exmen<-summary(geeglm(round ~ square,
                        data = ex, id = ideo,
                        corstr = "independence"))
    exmen

 Coefficients:
            Estimate Std.err Wald Pr(>|W|)  
(Intercept)   -0.510   0.229 4.95    0.026 *
square        -0.939   0.404 5.40    0.020 *
---
```

So I wonder 2 things.
1. Why I get results only for square?
2.(optional)Is it possible to recreate exactly the same table with `gee` or `geepack` as with spss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have specified square to be the only explanatory variable. The dependent variable LeftvsRight does not exist in R. When you add it, specify the model like this:

```
gee(LeftvsRight ~ square + round,data = ex, id = ideo,
                    corstr = "independence")
```

Comment: It should be the same as the id (ideo). Does it make sense?

Comment: In ideo, I see 0's and 1's. That specifies that the observations are made on 2 independent clusters, one identified by the zeros and the other by the ones. The manual says that "id" is a vector which identifies the clusters. It also says that: Data are assumed to be sorted so that observations on a cluster are contiguous rows for all entities in the formula [However ideo is not sorted]. Also, if there is dependence in the data, corstr = "independence" doesn't make much sense. corstr = "unstructured" makes more sense, although it depends on the problem. Type ?gee to see more options. HTH

Comment: I can't tell what options were used in spss from the output.

Comment: I have already checked correlation on my original dataset and this is why I used "idependence".

Comment: Anyway that works with independence, I wait if I will find an answer to the optional question I did or I ll accept your answer.

Comment: For the optional question, the least I will need is the options you used in spss. Generally, I think of R as much more extensive than SPSS and so I believe it should be possible.

Comment: How close or how far are the coefficients at the moment?